# Injection of a friend declaration into a namespace, Eckel, Vol1, pg:440?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand injection of a friend declaration into a namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Z { //forward declaration
  class X;
}

class Y {
   public:
   void func(Z::X*, int);
 };

namespace Z {
  class X {
    int i;
    public:
    X() : i(999) {}
    friend void Y::func(Z::X*, int);
    void print(void) { cout << i << endl; }
  };
}


void Y::func(Z::X* ptr, int i)
{
  ptr->i = 40;
}

int main(void)
{
  Z::X zx;
  zx.print();

  Y y;
  y.func(&zx, 40);
  zx.print();

  using namespace Z;
//  func(&zx, 30); DOES NOT WORK
}
```

> friendInject.cc:39: error: 'func' was not declared in this scope
>   The book says: "You can inject a friend declaration into a namespace by 
>   declaring it within an enclosed class". "Now the function you() is a member of
>   the namespace Me."

What exactly does this mean?? I tried Y::func but that perhaps works only for 
static member functions??

Comment: I bet that in the example in the book, the friend was **not** a member of another class. That makes a huge difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11 Standard 7.3.1.2 (3) says:

"If a friend declaration in a nonlocal class first declares a class or function **[footnote: this implies that the name of the class or function is unqualified]** the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace."

So any *unqualified* friend function declaration introduces a free function in the innermost enclosing namespace; (probably) the book referes to this as to "injection into namespace".

Note that it is even possible to define (implement) a function inside friend declaration:

```
namespace Z
{
  class C
  {
    friend void f(void){/*do something*/}
  };
}
```

This friend declaration not only "injects" but also implements free function f in the namespace Z (f is not a member of class C itself!), so no other declarations or definitions are needed for Z::f.

As to your example,

```
friend void Y::func(Z::X*, int);
```

is *qualified* (prefixed with namespace/class name), so it doesn't *declare* a function, it only refers to a member function Y::func previously declared in class Y. Such friend declarations "injects" nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you must write

```
y.func(&zx, 30); // work well
```

with y. Because fund - its a class instance method

Comment: could you elaborate a bit.. what exactly does he mean by "inject" a friend declaration into a namespace?? y.func() would work of course but the author means something more..something to do with namespace Z

Comment: couldn't you add this code with 'function you()' from your book? or what is page and book? i try to find it itself

Comment: www.lib.ru.ac.th/download/e-books/TIC2Vone.pdf (pg:440)

Comment: "Now the function you( )is a member of the namespace Me."
It's wrong. If I declare function such as in book's example, the function 'you' will not become a member of namespace 'Me'

Comment: @Ilya: it _will_ become  a member of namespace Me. Indeed, you may invoke function Me::you() wherever possible in the program after this friend declaration (no other declarations needed for the function).